# Как дождаться завершения всех функций запущенных в цикле $each

Tags: javascript, jquery, многопоточность, циклы, async-await

У меня такой код:

```
getFilms() {
    $.each(filmArray, (index, item) => {
        this.homeService.getFilmInfo(item, async (result) => {
            this.moviesRenderer.renderMovies(result);
        });
    });

    // add click handlers for moies list
    this.productService.addMovieHandlers();
}
```

Проблема в том, что функции, запущенные в цикле, завершаются после завершения метода getFilms, как я могу дождаться завершения всех функций. В массиве 15 элементов.

Я пробовал использовать Promise, но ничего не вышло, может я что-то делаю не так.

Я также записывал каждую запущенную функцию в список Promise, а затем ожидал их завершения с помощью Promise.all, но это тоже не сработало, метод также завершился до завершения всех функций. Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне дождаться завершения всех запущенных в цикле функций.

Пробовал async/await и Promise так:

```
getFilms() {
    let promises = [];

    $.each(filmArray, (index, item) => {
        promises.push(new Promise(() => {
            await this.homeService.getFilmInfo(item, async (result) => {
                await this.moviesRenderer.renderMovies(result);
            });
        }))
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
        // Do work
    });
}

getFilmInfo(path, callback) {
    $.get(path, (result) => {
        callback(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: покажи как ты пробовал с Promise и Promise.all. А так же добавь пример реализации той функции, которую ты хочешь дождаться.

Comment: отредактировать вопрос ты можешь с помощью кнопки [edit]

Comment: Добавь код в сам вопрос.

Comment: еще добавь пример `this.homeService.getShortMoviesList` и `this.moviesShortListRenderer.renderMoviesList`

Comment: @Grundy getShortMoviesList просто гет запросом получает данные и колбэком возвращает, а renderMoviesList() отображает эти данные

Comment: @Grundy там никаких сложных конструкций нету

Comment: Нужен именно пример реализации, чтобы стало ясно каким именно способом решить проблему

Comment: @Grundy сори но больше данных я не могу представить(

Comment: На данный момент у тебя собралось все в кучу `promise`, `async/await`, `callback` чтобы понять, что нужно, а что можно выкинуть, нужны примеры всех функций

Comment: @Grundy, я пробовал и без async/await, только с промисом, но это не помогло

Comment: Для решения нужно знать, как именно ты делаешь запрос и что возвращаешь из функции

Comment: `renderMovies` - синхронная функция?

Comment: @Grundy Я её делал и синхронной и асинхронной

Comment: @Grundy изначально была синхронная

Comment: @Grundy, в ней результат отображается на странице, она ничего не возвращает

Comment: а чего ты `getFilmInfo` удалил?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как функция `getFilmInfo` не возвращает `Promise` ее нельзя дождаться с помощью `await`.

Однако, ее вызов можно обернуть в конструктор [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Конструктор, в качестве первого параметра принимает функцию с двумя аргументами:

1. вызов первого переводит Promise в success состояние
2. вызов второго переводит Promise в error состояние

Таким образом код обертки может выглядеть так:

```
new Promise(resolve => this.homeService.getFilmInfo(item, resolve))
```

Теперь можно, можно работать с результатом, как с Promise

В итоге получится следующее:

```
async getFilms() {
    var itemsPromises = $.map(items, async (item) => {
        var result = await new Promise(resolve => this.homeService.getFilmInfo(item, resolve));
        this.moviesRenderer.renderMovies(result)
    });
    
    await Promise.all(itemsPromises);
    
    // Do work
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую)

Comment: спасибо, все заработало)

Comment: @Igor, если ответ помог, можешь его галочкой отметить

Comment: а если мне нужно подождать пока отработает renderMovies, его также нужно вызвать как и getFilmInfo?

Comment: @Igor, если это синхронная функция, ты и так ее ждешь сейчас. то что после Promise.all - это когда выполнятся все запросы и все рендеры

Comment: ок, понял, спасибо)